# Reverse for 'filename' not found. 'filename' is not a valid view function or pattern name

Tags: python, html, django, jinja2, django-urls

i am trying to redirect from my menu item to another page with some parameter in django

i am writting code like this

```
 <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="{% url 'MscItPdf_Note' '1' 'SC' %}">Soft Computing</a>
```

for this url.py is

```
path('MscItPdf_Note/<str:semester>/<slug:subject>/',views.MscItPdf_Note,name='MscItPdf_Note')
```

and in **views.py**

```
def MscItPdf_Note(request,semester,subject):
    pdfNotes_file=MscItPDF_Notes.objects.all().filter(subject=subject)
    n=len(pdfNotes_file)
    print("hello",pdfNotes_file)
    params={'pdfnote':pdfNotes_file,'total_items':n}
    return render(request,'pdfNotes.html',params)
```

it gives error like this

```
NoReverseMatch at /MscItPdf_Note/1/SC/         
Reverse for 'filename' not found. 'filename' is not a valid view function or pattern name.
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/pdfNote/5/MIS/
Django Version: 3.2.7
Exception Type: NoReverseMatch
Exception Value:    
Reverse for 'filename' not found. 'filename' is not a valid view function or pattern name.
Exception Location: C:\Users\ashwi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py, line 694, in _reverse_with_prefix
Python Executable:  C:\Users\ashwi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\python.exe
Python Version: 3.9.7
```

**ERROR TRACEBACK FROM TERMINAL**

```
Internal Server Error: /pdfNote/4/MIS/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\ashwi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 47, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\ashwi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 181, in _get_response     
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\ashwi\Documents\GitHub\Summer Project\studimates\StudiMates_mk1\views.py", line 91, in pdfNote
    return render(request,'pdfNotes.html',params)
  File "C:\Users\ashwi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\shortcuts.py", line 19, in render
    content = loader.render_to_string(template_name, context, request, 
using=using)
  File "C:\Users\ashwi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader.py", line 62, in render_to_string      
    return template.render(context, request)
  File "C:\Users\ashwi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\template\backends\django.py", line 61, in render       
    return self.template.render(context)
  File "C:\Users\ashwi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 170, in render
    return self._render(context)
  File "C:\Users\ashwi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 162, in _render
    return self.nodelist.render(context)
  File "C:\Users\ashwi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 938, in render
    bit = node.render_annotated(context)
  File "C:\Users\ashwi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 905, in render_annotated       
    return self.render(context)
  File "C:\Users\ashwi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader_tags.py", line 150, in render
    return compiled_parent._render(context)
  File "C:\Users\ashwi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 162, in _render
    return self.nodelist.render(context)
  File "C:\Users\ashwi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 938, in render
    bit = node.render_annotated(context)
  File "C:\Users\ashwi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 905, in render_annotated       
    return self.render(context)
  File "C:\Users\ashwi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader_tags.py", line 62, in render
    result = block.nodelist.render(context)
  File "C:\Users\ashwi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 938, in render
    bit = node.render_annotated(context)
  File "C:\Users\ashwi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 905, in render_annotated       
    return self.render(context)
  File "C:\Users\ashwi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\template\defaulttags.py", line 446, in render
    url = reverse(view_name, args=args, kwargs=kwargs, current_app=current_app)
  File "C:\Users\ashwi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\urls\base.py", line 86, in reverse
    return resolver._reverse_with_prefix(view, prefix, *args, **kwargs)  File "C:\Users\ashwi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 694, in 
_reverse_with_prefix
    raise NoReverseMatch(msg)
django.urls.exceptions.NoReverseMatch: Reverse for 'filename' not found. 'filename' is not a valid view function or pattern name.
[26/Sep/2021 00:52:00] "GET /pdfNote/4/MIS/ HTTP/1.1" 500 164089
```

where am i making wrong? and what's the solution for this?

Comment: Looks like your `pdfNotes.html` has a `{% url 'filename' ... %}`, and that view does not exists.

Comment: Share the full error traceback (from terminal not from web)

Comment: No there is no "filename" in pdfNotes.html

Comment: here's the errror tracebavk from terminal

Comment: please show the whole template. The line in your question is most likely not the troublemaker - if you remove it, does the problem persist? If yes, look elsewhere.